# Split oracle fetched data into 4 columns

Tags: php, oracle

I have Select view from oracle which returns me 11 rows.
I want to fetch data and print them into 4 columns. Should be like:

```
Item 1     Item 2     Item 3      Item 4 
Item 5     Item 6     Item 7      Item 8
Item 9     Item 10    Item 11     Item 12
Item 13.......
```

Here is my code for 2 columns. But how to do it for 4 columns?

Also I do not understand why `oci_num_rows` shows row count only after `while(oci_fecth_data)`

```
<?php
$stmt1 = oci_parse($conn, $query1);
oci_execute($stmt1);
$mssqlaray = array();
$index = 0;
while (($row1 = oci_fetch_array($stmt1, OCI_BOTH))) 
{
  $mssqlaray[$index] = $row1;
    $index++;
}

for($j = 0; $j < oci_num_rows($stmt1); $j+=2)
{
  echo '
  <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="checkbox1'.$mssqlaray[$j][0].'" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox1'.$mssqlaray[$j][0].'">'.$mssqlaray[$j][1].'   </label>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
for($j = 1; $j < oci_num_rows($stmt1); $j+=2)
{
    echo '
  <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="checkbox1'.$mssqlaray[$j][0].'"type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox1'.$mssqlaray[$j][0].'">'.$mssqlaray[$j][1].'</label>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: `oci_num_rows`: Returns number of rows affected during statement execution (Taken from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php)). So, it can only know how many rows are affected, after the affected data is fetched, I assume.

How many items are in each row?

Comment: Why do you have two loops here?  This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Geshode for `sqlsrv` it works after `sqlsrv_query` I can use `sqlsrv_num_rows`, but it is working different for `OCI`. I have 2 columns for each row.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did it easy wat for 2 rows and found that I need 4.

Comment: So, you want to show 22 items in total?

Comment: @Geshode No, I need print 11 rows into 4 columns, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, but you said, that each of the 11 rows has 2 columns. That is why I asked, if you want to show 22 items (11rows x 2 columns) in total.

Comment: @Geshode sorry, my fault. I need to show 11 items into 4 columns.

Comment: Ah, okay. I guess, you could echo the data with a for loop into a table and use an if clause to go to the next table row, when i%4 == 0. Assuming, you use i as your for loop variable.

Comment: @Geshode what is `i` in your code? is it `oci_num_rows`?

Comment: i is the variable of the for loop like in:
`for(i=0; i<11; i++)`.

Comment: @geshode row counts can change anytime, therefore i should use `oci_num_rows` and it possible to get number of rows only after `while`. That`s confuse me)

Comment: Well, then you just change the for loop to: `for(i=0; i<count($mssqlaray); i++)`. That way it doesn't matter, if the number of results change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you wanted, if I understood correctly. Of course you can still add things like div or classes. I thought, I just give you the skeleton of my approach.

```
<?php
$stmt1 = oci_parse($conn, $query1);
oci_execute($stmt1);
$mssqlaray = array();
$index = 0;
while (($row1 = oci_fetch_array($stmt1, OCI_BOTH))) 
{
    $mssqlaray[$index] = $row1;
    $index++;
}

echo '<table>'."\n";
echo '<tr>'."\n";

for($i = 0; $i < count($mssqlaray); $i++)
{
    echo '<td>'.$mssqlaray[$i].'</td>';
    if(i == 3 || i == 7 || i == 11){
        echo '</tr>'."\n";
        echo '<tr>'."\n";
    }
}
echo '</tr>'."\n";
echo '</table>."\n";
?>
```

Comment: I also did same, there is one problem that I need to show data sequentially. But İ got 1 column with 2 data, 2 columns 4 data and 1 column 1 data(

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What exactly is the problem? Please be more specific.

Comment: I noticed a mental error in my approach. I changed it and it should work now.

Comment: You are awesome!) thank you very much!) Now I understand my mistake thanx to you!)

Comment: I am glad, we could find a solution to your problem.